# Error with Mega2560 via SPI

Tags: arduino-mega, spi

I tried the following code to communicate via SPI with MPU9250 and Mega2560 But I got the following error:
**Error initializing communication with IMU**

Why I got this error?

```c
/*
* Brian R Taylor
* brian.taylor@bolderflight.com
* 
* Copyright (c) 2021 Bolder Flight Systems Inc
*
* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
* of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to
* deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the
* rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
* sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
* furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
* all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*
* THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
* IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
* AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
* FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
* IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

#include "mpu9250.h"

/* Mpu9250 object, SPI bus, CS on pin 10 */
bfs::Mpu9250 imu(&SPI, 10);

void setup() {
  /* Serial to display data */
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial) {}
  /* Start the SPI bus */
  SPI.begin();
  /* Initialize and configure IMU */
  if (!imu.Begin()) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing communication with IMU");
    while(1) {}
  }
  /* Set the sample rate divider */
  if (!imu.ConfigSrd(19)) {
    Serial.println("Error configured SRD");
    while(1) {}
  }
}

void loop() {
  /* Check if data read */
  if (imu.Read()) {
    Serial.print(imu.new_imu_data());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.new_mag_data());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.accel_x_mps2());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.accel_y_mps2());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.accel_z_mps2());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.gyro_x_radps());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.gyro_y_radps());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.gyro_z_radps());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.mag_x_ut());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.mag_y_ut());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.mag_z_ut());
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(imu.die_temp_c());
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
}
```

Source code:

https://github.com/bolderflight/invensense-imu/blob/main/examples/arduino/mpu9250/spi/spi.ino

Connection:

```
MPU9250                 Mega 2560
    GND <.............> GND
    3V3 <.............> 3.3V
    SCL <.............> pin 52
    SDA <.............> pin 51
SDC/SA0 <.............> pin 50
    CSB <.............> pin 53
```

This is the sensor ( IMU 10DOF SENSOR MODULE MPU9250 BMP280 ( GY-91 ))
But I only interested on the MODULE MPU9250 readings via SPI

[image]

Comment: Is your Mega 5 VDC? Do the I/Os on the MPU9250 operate at 3.3 volts or are they 5 volt tolerant?

Comment: did you use the correct pins?

Comment: you got that error because the following program line runs when IMU does not return a **successful start** status ... `Serial.println("Error initializing communication with IMU");`

Comment: so, your question should really be asking `why does imu.Begin() fail?`